# Is there a remote service like teamviwer or gotomypc for shell/console?

Tags: ubuntu, remote-access

I have to manage a number of servers and workstations at various locations. They are not connected via a VPN since they are not part of the same organization. They are just servers that I look after. All run Ubuntu Linux.

I was wondering if there's a service that might help me admin them. It would need to be a bit like TeamViewer but for consoles. I'd like to be able to install something on each PC so that as long as the PC was on the internet I could login. I've tried using TeamViewer - it's not reliable enough and I really don't need support for graphical applications.

I'd like not to have to set up SSH port-forwards on the routers for each machine since I cannot count on routers being set up consistently.

Ideally this service would connect up to the remote admin service and let me login remotely any time I need it. The login would only have to give me a regular console. Does such a product exist?

Comment: Use IPv6 wherever possible and the problem goes away. Also consider setting up your own VPN.

Comment: I cannot upvote Michael Hampton's comment enough times.  IPv6 is *the* answer.  Then it's just SSH to everything, all the time.

Comment: Is there a primer on how to do this? I'd need to get each of the machines I care about assigned to a name (dyndns might help?). All of the machines are behind ddwrt (or very similar) routers, which support IP6.